# 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have cancel button that is not working properly on a JQuery Modal Dialog and I would really appreciate some help. 
This is the exception I'm getting when I click on the cancel button of the modal:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog
>   prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

This is the partial view I'm displaying on the modal:

```
@model Models.Office
@{  
    Layout = null;
}
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseModal() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        }
</script>


@*@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditOffice", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "edit-Dialog" }))*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEditOffice", "Admin", "POST"))
{ 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Office</legend>
        @if (ViewBag.IsUpdate == true)
        { 
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OfficeId)
        }

        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OfficeName)
        </div>
        <div class="Input-medium">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OfficeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.OfficeName)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupportNo)
        </div>
        <div class="Input-medium">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupportNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportNo)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupportEmail)
        </div>
        <div class="Input-medium">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupportEmail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportEmail)
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupportFax)
        </div>
        <div class="Input-medium">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupportFax)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportFax)
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupportFtp)
        </div>
        <div class="Input-medium">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupportFtp)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportFtp)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <div class="pull-right">
        @if (ViewBag.IsUpdate == true)
        { 
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnUpdate" name="Command" value ="Update">Update</button>
        }
        else
        { 
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Command" value="Save">Save</button>
        }
            <button type="button" id="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CloseModal()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
}
```

Then this is the scrip on the parent view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".editDialog").on("click", function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault(); use this or return false
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                title: 'Edit Office',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 450,
                width: 380,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(url);
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#dialog-edit").dialog().dialog('close');
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });   
</script>
```

What I'm I doing wrong ????

Comment: Side note: You should use `.dialog({ autoOpen: false })` instead of `.dialog().dialog('close')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inline handlers such as `onclick="CloseModal()"` do not set the `this` inside the function being called. You have to pass the `this` reference inline:

```
onclick="CloseModal(this)"

function CloseModal(el) {
    $(el).dialog("close");
}
```

---

Or just attach the handler with jQuery and it will set the `this` reference inside of the event handler:

```
//instead of onclick="", attach the handler inside DOM ready:
$(function() {
    $('#Cancel').click(CloseModal);
});
function CloseModal() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

This assumes `#Cancel` is present when the page structure is finished rendering and that your markup is valid (no duplicated IDs).

Comment: Thanks @Fabricio for your prompt help mate !

Comment: This is the error message its throwing now:

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Comment: Can you put the rendered HTML and the JS in http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue? It is likely that either `CloseModal()` is being called before the first `.dialog({/*opts*/})` or there's still a reference error regarding `this`.

Comment: Also add a `console.log(this)`/`console.log(el)` before the `.dialog('close')` to check whether that function is actually the culprit and whether it is actually referencing to the correct element.

Comment: obrigado @Fabrício pela sua ajuda. 

Como eu estava encalhado neste problema eu resolvi usar uma outra alternativa que funcionou.  

A unica desvantagem e que tenho de voltar ao controller... mas funciona, para ja vai ter de servir infelizemente...

Obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 3):

$(this).dialog( "close" );

instead of "this" use name of dialog eg..$("header").dialog("close");

It works for me.

Regards

Bhaskar.